# How to change ip address of adaptor?

Tags: c#, windows-7, network-programming

I want to set IP address in adaptor. I got several reference for below code. but after executing this, when I check adaptor ip adress, it is not changing. It shows me old ip address always. Not giving any error/exception.
How to change ip address of adaptor?

Refere [Dynamic-ip-change-in-c#](http://microsoftdotnetsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/12/dynamic-ip-change-in-c.html)

```
/// <summary>
        /// Set's a new IP Address and it's Submask of the local machine
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ipAaddress">The IP Address</param>
        /// <param name="subnetMask">The Submask IP Address</param>
        /// <remarks>Requires a reference to the System.Management namespace</remarks>
        public void SetIP(string ipAaddress, string subnetMask)
        {
            ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
            ManagementObjectCollection managementObjectCollection = managementClass.GetInstances();
            foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in managementObjectCollection)
            {
                if ((bool)managementObject["IPEnabled"])
                {
                    try
                    {       
                        string[] addresses = (string[])managementObject["IPAddress"];
                        //Console.WriteLine(addresses[0]);
                        if (addresses[0] == "xxx.xx.xxx.xx")                                 //xxx.xx.xxx.xx should be some valid ip
                        {
                            ManagementBaseObject managementBaseObjectNew = managementObject.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
                            managementBaseObjectNew["IPAddress"] = new string[] { ipAaddress };
                            managementBaseObjectNew["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnetMask };
                            ManagementBaseObject managementBaseObjectSet = managementObject.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", managementBaseObjectNew, null);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but i faced the same problem and solved it by running the program as Administrator. I used the same technic (WMI), but with different code, that i posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333683/how-to-set-ip-address-of-device-connected-to-host-pc-c-sharp-winform). Hope that helps...