# How to set IP address of device connected to Host PC? C# Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, tcp

I have a Modbus TCP/IP to MODBUS RTU converter , which comes with a default IP of 192.168.0.1 . I need to develop a small c# Winform app to change this device's IP address to any desired IP address. How do I do that?.

Comment: This has nothing to do with winforms.

Comment: I want to develop C# WinForm application on Host PC to set IP address of the device.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with WMI ([Windows Management Instrumentation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation)).

First, you have to add the reference for `System.Management` to your Project.

Second, you need to find the `NetworkInterface` for your network connection by name:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Management;

public class NetworkManager
{
    public static NetworkInterface GetNetworkInterface(string sName)
    {
        NetworkInterface NetInterface = null;

        // Precondition
        if (sName == "") return null;

        NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach (NetworkInterface ni in interfaces)
        {
            if (ni.Name == sName)
            {
                NetInterface = ni;
                break;
            }
        }

        return NetInterface;
    }
```

Third, you have to create a `ManagementObject` for your `NetworkInterface`:

```
    public static ManagementObject GetNetworkAdapterManagementObject(NetworkInterface NetInterface)
    {
        ManagementObject oMngObj = null;

        // Precondition
        if (NetInterface == null) return null;

        string sNI = NetInterface.Id;

        ManagementClass oMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection oMOC = oMC.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject oMO in oMOC)
        {
            string sMO = oMO["SettingID"].ToString();
            if (sMO == sNI)
            {
                // Found
                oMngObj = oMO;
                break;
            }
        }

        return oMngObj;
    }
```

Fours, you can set the ipadress with:

```
    public static bool SetIPAdress(ManagementObject oMO, string[] saIPAdress, string[] saSubnetMask)
    {
        bool bErg = false;
        try
        {
            // Precondition
            if (oMO == null) return false;
            if (saIPAdress == null) return false;
            if (saSubnetMask == null) return false;

            // Get ManagementBaseObject 
            ManagementBaseObject oNewIP = null;
            oNewIP = oMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");

            oNewIP["IPAddress"] = saIPAdress;
            oNewIP["SubnetMask"] = saSubnetMask;

            // Invoke
            oMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", oNewIP, null);

            // Alles ok
            bErg = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SetIPAdress failed: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return bErg;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it, for example in a button click event handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sConn = "LAN-Verbindung";
    NetworkInterface oNI = NetworkManager.GetNetworkInterface(sConn);
    ManagementObject oMO = NetworkManager.GetNetworkAdapterManagementObject(oNI);

    string sIPAdress = "192.168.1.1";
    string sSubnetMask = "255.255.255.0";
    string[] saIPAdress = {sIPAdress};
    string[] saSubnetMask = {sSubnetMask};
    if (NetworkManager.SetIPAdress(oMO, saIPAdress, saSubnetMask))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yes...");
    }
}
```

Depending on the policies on your pc, may be you have to run the program as Administrator...

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. However, what you answered is setting up the ip address of the Host PC where application is running.  What I need is , setting up the IP address of device which is connected to Host PC. Please help.

Comment: Well, yes, it should be possible, also I never tried. When you create 'ManagementClass' (in GetNetworkAdapterManagementObject) you give a so called 'ManagementPath' (here "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration". You could give something like "\\\\ComputerName\\root\\cimv2:Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" where 'ComputerName' is the name of the target machine. I think you need login credential on that machine for this and WMI as to be enabled for network some how. And you have to know the NetworkInterface.Id on that machine...

Comment: I just realized that your converter device will probably not run on windows, so the way mentioned above will not work at all. What protocols and/or tools does this device offer?

Comment: device (converter) offers SNMP,TCP/IP